# How to specify a day and time as breakpoint in sql?

Tags: c#, sql

I need to display 12/29 - 01/04, 01/05 - 01/11, etc in a dropdown from Wednesday to tuesday depending on what date is now. 
Before Monday ie., 12/27 6:00pm, it should display from 12/29 - 01/04, after monday ie., after 6:00pm, the dropdown should display 01/05-01/11.
I hope you guys understand what i want. I have no idea how i can set a day and time as breakpoint and get weeks from the database. The database has Column StartDate as 12/29/2010 12:00:00AM and EndDate as 01/04/2011 12:00:00AM,etcc

Where can i specify what i want, either in C# or Sql. and get weeks accordingly? In sql, how should be the stored Procedure.. Someone please help me out..

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick - you need to use [DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx?PHPSESSID=lm71lj7i6gj5fjtebtb2srl4n3) to set the first day of the week to Wednesday.  You can then use a little manipulation to get the dates you want.

```
Set DateFirst 3
Declare @CurrentDate datetime,
        @Start datetime,
        @End datetime

Select @CurrentDate = getdate()

Select  @Start = Case 
        When (DATEPART(DW, @CurrentDate) = 6 and DATEPART(hour, @currentDate) > 18)
                or (DATEPART(DW, @CurrentDate) > 6 ) Then 
            DateAdd(day, ((7 - DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)+1) + 7), @CurrentDate)
            Else DateAdd(day, ((7 - DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDate)+1)), @CurrentDate)
         End

Select @End = DATEADD(day, 6, @start)

Select @CurrentDate, @Start, @End
```

Comment: @Ram - no problem at all. Glad to help